# file exists or not through matching list of file names provided

Tags: python, csv, os.path

i have files in folders and subfolders.
folder structure is like this

```
2020(folder)
-01(sub folder)
--14(sub-sub folder)
----abc1-2020-01-14.csv
----abc2-2020-01-14.csv
-02(subfolder in 2020)
--17(sub-sub folder in 02)
----abc1-2020-02-17.csv
----abc4-2020-02-17.csv
```

now i have list of file names.

```
li = ['abc1','abc2','abc3','abc4']
```

i want to know if these file exists in directory or not. each subdirectory should have all 4 files. if not then code must return path where particular file doesnot exist.

what i have tried

```
BASE_PATH = r'2020/'
all_files = glob.glob(BASE_PATH + "**/*.csv",recursive=True)

li = ['abc1','abc2','abc3','abc4']
for filename in all_files:
    h = os.path.split(filename)
    print("Head of '% s:'" % os.path, h[0]) 
    print("Tail of '% s:'" % os.path, h[1], "\n")
    for fn in li:
        if (head_tail[1].startswith(fn)):
            print('True', os.path(filename))
        else:
            print('False', os.path(filename))
```

any help would be great.

Comment: What specific issue(s) do you have with what you have tried?

Comment: well if i removes os.path(filename) from print commands, then itws returning just list of False. WITH os.path(filename) its giving error

Comment: "its giving error": WHAT error?

Comment: i have updated question sort out something, dont know how to change here so i post another question with different code, kindly have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889174/file-exists-or-not-through-matching-filename-in-list